# BigQuery Basics - FROM clause while quering

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

A very basic question. I have a query as follows:

What does the FROM clause mean here?

```
SELECT [device.deviceCategory] as [device_Category] 
FROM [project-id:dataset.ga_sessions_20150309] [ga_sessions_20150309]  
GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY [device_Category] ASC
```

What is the difference between the following two FROM clauses?

```
FROM [project-id:dataset.ga_sessions_20150309] [ga_sessions_20150309]

FROM [project-id:dataset.ga_sessions_20150309]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base on what i see on your query , you just giving it Aliases. Just like the example below

```
SELECT * FROM StudentInformation as StudentProfile;
```

Comment: That was way too basic! Thanks for patiently answering the question :)